# C++ Issue with Polymorphism - Data overwritten

Tags: c++, oop, object

I got this example

Parent class `Vehicle`

Child Classes `Car`, `Motorcycle`, & `Lorry`

This is what happens: In `main.cpp` I create

```
VehicleTwoD *vehicletwod[100];
Car *myCar = new Car();
Motorcycle *myMotorcycle = new motorCycle();
Lorry *myLorry = new Lorry();
```

This is what I do:

```
if(selection=="Car")
{
   vehicletwod[arrayCounter] = myCar;
   vehicletwod[arrayCounter]->setName(theName);
   vehicletwod[arrayCounter]->setYear(theYear);
}

if(selection=="Lorry")
{
   vehicletwod[arrayCounter] = myLorry;
   vehicletwod[arrayCounter]->setName(theName);
   vehicletwod[arrayCounter]->setYear(theYear);
}

if(selection=="Motorcycle")
{
   vehicletwod[arrayCounter] = myMotorcycle ;
   vehicletwod[arrayCounter]->setName(theName);
   vehicletwod[arrayCounter]->setYear(theYear);
}

cout << "Record successfully stored. Going back to the main menu " << endl;
```

The issue here in `main.cpp` is some kind of `switch-case` menu with a prompt, so if the user chooses to insert a new vehicle, he selects the vehicle type, and will manually input some value like `theName` and `theYear`. Then it will be set to the `vehicletwod[arrayCounter]`.

The program runs into an issue when there is more than 1 object of the same child type in the list of `vehicletwod`.

If the user does something like

```
Car
Motorcycle
Car
```

The 1st car value will be overwritten by the latest `Car` (the 2nd car)

However, if they input

```
Car 
Motorcycle
Lorry
```

Itis fine because each object only runs once.

How do I change my declaration so it will not overwrite the data of the previous same child class.

Comment: Please show the code where you manipulate arrayCounter.  In fact, please just show _all_ the code, if that's too long reduce it to the simplest code you can make that still shows the problem.  You're asking people to diagnose problems in code they can't see. One of the below guesses could be correct, but whether or no, right now they're all guesses all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new `Car` , `Motorcycle` and `Lorry` instance for each new entry, since now you reuse the exiting instances and in that way rewrite data. You should do:

```
if(selection=="Car")
{
   vehicletwod[arrayCounter] = new Car();
   vehicletwod[arrayCounter]->setName(theName);
   vehicletwod[arrayCounter]->setYear(theYear);
}

if(selection=="Lorry")
{
   vehicletwod[arrayCounter] = new Lorry();
   vehicletwod[arrayCounter]->setName(theName);
   vehicletwod[arrayCounter]->setYear(theYear);
}

if(selection=="Motorcycle")
{
   vehicletwod[arrayCounter] = new Motorcycle();
   vehicletwod[arrayCounter]->setName(theName);
   vehicletwod[arrayCounter]->setYear(theYear);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time you choose a new vehicle, you must create a brand new object to hold it. Replace your line:

```
vehicletwod[arrayCounter] = myCar;
```

with:

```
vehicletwod[arrayCounter] = new Car;
```

And likewise for the other types.